# (Double) Recursive generic parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, inheritance, constraints

I'm trying to make two interfaces linked together like this:

```
Public Interface A(Of Out T As B(Of A(Of T)))
    ...
End Interface
Public Interface B(Of Out T As A(Of B(Of T)))
    ...
End Interface
```

The problem is that I get the error 'Type argument `A(Of T)` does not inherit from or implement the constraint type `A(Of B(Of A(Of T)))`', but why not?

`T` does inherit from `B(Of A(Of T))` and is an `Out` generic type, right?

**UPDATE:** The reason for this construction is that upon implementation of `A`, I want this type to be linked to another type `B`, by setting the type argument `T` to the interface `B` with type parameter the original class, like this:

```
Class AA
    Implements A(Of BB)
    ...
End Class
Class BB
    Implements B(Of AA)
    ...
End Class
```

The interfaces will then each have one function:

```
Public Interface A(Of Out T As B(Of A(Of T)))
    Function getB() As T
End Interface
Public Interface B(Of Out T As A(Of B(Of T)))
    ReadOnly Property myA As T
End Interface
```

The function `getB` returns one instance of `B` and the function `myA` returns the linked instance of `A`. Perhaps there is another way to design this, but I would still want to know what the error I get actually means. Hopefully somebody understands why I get this error.

Comment: Perhaps if you can explain what the relationship is meant to be between the two classes that implement these interfaces, we might be able to suggest the correct annotations (or tell you that what you're trying to enforce isn't enforceable in generics)

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve isn't enforceable in generics - it seems *similar* to the examples given in Eric Lippert's [Curiouser and curiouser blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) (it's C# but the same limits apply in VB)

Comment: I've provided an answer that does provide you with what you want. You can maintain a strongly-typed double recursive class structure all the way down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what I think you want like this:

```
Public Interface A(Of TA As A(Of TA, TB), Out TB As B(Of TA, TB))
    Function GetB() As TB
End Interface

Public Interface B(Of Out TA As A(Of TA, TB), TB As B(Of TA, TB))
    ReadOnly Property myA() As TA
End Interface
```

Then define your classes like this:

```
Public Class AA
    Implements A(Of AA, BB)
    Public Function GetB() As BB Implements A(Of AA, BB).GetB
        Return New BB()
    End Function
End Class

Public Class BB
    Implements B(Of AA, BB)
    Public ReadOnly Property myA() As AA Implements B(Of AA, BB).myA
        Get
            Return New AA()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

This compiles and works for me.

You can even implement this with abstract classes to get rid of the `Implements` syntax like so:

```
Public MustInherit Class XA(Of TA As A(Of TA, TB), TB As B(Of TA, TB))
    Implements A(Of TA, TB)
    Public MustOverride Function GetB() As TB Implements A(Of TA, TB).GetB
End Class

Public MustInherit Class XB(Of TA As A(Of TA, TB), TB As B(Of TA, TB))
    Implements B(Of TA, TB)
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property myA() As TA Implements B(Of TA, TB).myA
End Class

Public Class AA
    Inherits XA(Of AA, BB)
    Public Overrides Function GetB() As BB
        Return New BB()
    End Function
End Class

Public Class BB
    Inherits XB(Of AA, BB)
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property myA() As AA
        Get
            Return New AA()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Wow I didn't expect this to be possible! This is exactly what I meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this hard on yourself. Why are you turning interfaces A and B into generic types? I guess it is because you want the implementations of methods myA and getB to have a return type that matches the concrete class instances returned (i.e. AA and BB). Ask yourself why you need this; is there a public/friend method in class AA or BB that is missing in interface A or B? If so, then this might be sign of code smell; you may want to refactor.

Some wise words from Robert C. Martin: "Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions."

```
Public Interface A
    Function getB() As B
End Interface

Public Interface B
    ReadOnly Property myA As A
End Interface

Public Class AA
    Implements A

    Public Function getB() As B       ' the return type is still B
        Return New BB()               ' but the return value is an instance of BB
    End Function
End Class

Public Class BB
    Implements B

    Public ReadOnly Property myA As A ' the return type is still A
        Get
            Return New AA()           ' but the return value is an instance of AA
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

As for your final question: I understand your curiosity, but any more digging for the exact reason of the error is a waste of time. In my own painful experience, when you get an error like this, it just means you are going the wrong way; reconsider and refactor your code!

Comment: Yes you are right and this solution was what I eventually ended up doing. It doesn't actully explain the error, but I will accept it anyway. Thank you for your explanation!